# mongodb C driver query to select specific field

Tags: c, mongodb, field

Ive read that it is possible to select only one field in MongoDB:

```
db.records.find({TimeStampSec {$lt:10} , {ch11:1})
```

For example, this query returns the field ch11 of all objects that have the TimeStampSec<10. But I don't know how to translate to C driver. I tried this:

```
bson_init( &query );
 bson_append_start_object( &query, "TimeStampSec" );
 bson_append_int( &query, "$lt", 10 );
 bson_append_finish_object( &query );

 bson_append_int( &query, "node_id", 1 );

 bson_finish( &query );
```

But, it does not work. Should I have to create another object?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely familar with the c api but i guess you should add a second json obj.

so eventually something like this:

```
bson_init( &query );
  bson_append_start_object( &query, "TimeStampSec" );
    bson_append_int( &query, "$lt", 10 );
  bson_append_finish_object( &query );

  bson_append_start_object( &query, "$query" );
    bson_append_int( &query, "ch11", 1 );
  bson_append_finish_object( &query );
bson_finish( &query );
```

?

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.

```
bson query,selection;
bson_init( &query );
  bson_append_start_object( &query, "TimeStampSec" );
    bson_append_int( &query, "$lt", 10 );
  bson_append_finish_object( &query );
bson_finish( &query );

bson_init( &selection);
    bson_append_int( &selection, "ch11", 1 );
bson_finish( &selection);

    mongo_cursor *cursor=NULL;

    cursor = mongo_find( conn, "db.records",query ,selection,0,0,0);

    if(cursor!=NULL)
    {
        while( mongo_cursor_next( cursor ) == MONGO_OK )
            bson_print( &cursor->current );
    }
```